# sublime text: jumping to top when saving

Tags: sublimetext3

I have sublime-text 4

I ran in safe mode using

```
subl -n -a --safe-mode .
```

But when I save it the cursor goes to top. I think if it has some lint errors it jumps to that point.

HOw to stop this.

Comment: If you're running in Safe Mode then you shouldn't have any linters running, unless you install Package Control and then install the linters every time you start Sublime...

Comment: In safe mode there should not be any linters. Then still why it keeps jumping up.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't replicate your behavior. Try uninstalling and reinstalling the latest build (4113 as of now) from scratch and see if that changes the behavior.

Comment: I have removed `.config/sublime-text-3` then it works. But then `safe mode` is supposed to use fresh.